# How to separate a string that can be dynamic using certain words

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to separate a certain string based on certain keys and add them to a map in key value pairs. The keys can change position. I'm new to regex and would like some assistance in completing it.

I have a string `"key1=valueforkey1&key2=valueforkey2"`. This string can also change to `"key2=valueforkey2&key1=valueforkey1"`.

My regex works for the above and separates the keys and values correctly.

It doesnt work when the value includes "=" before the key.

For example

```
"key1=valueforkey1=&key2=valueforkey2"
```

or

```
"key1=valueforkey1==&key2=valueforkey2".
```

My map will contain

```
map("key1", "valueforkey1")
```

and

```
map("key2", "valueforkey2")
```

instead of

```
map("key1", "valueforkey1==") 

map("key2", "valueforkey2")
```

```java
String delimiter = "[= & ?]+";
String[] split = text.split(delimiter );
for (int i=0; i<split.length; i+=2) {
    maps.put(split[i], split[i+1]);
}
```

I expect to separate the string and add them in key value pairs in a map.

```
map("key1", "valueforkey1") or

map("key1", "valueforkey1=") or

map("key1", "valueforkey1==")
```

and

```
map("key2", "valueforkey2") or

map("key2", "valueforkey2=") or

map("key2", "valueforkey2==")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
([^=&\s]+)=(.*?)(?=&[^=&\s]+=|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/khE3Ge/2).

- `([^=&\\s]+)` - Group 1: any 1+ chars other than `=`, `&` and whitespace
- `=` - a `=` sign
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=&[^=&\\s]+=|$)` - immediately to the right of the current location, there must be `&` followed with 1+ chars  other than `=`, `&` and whitespace and then `=` or end of string.

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/LgLpsT):

```
String str = "key1=valueforkey1==&key2=valueforkey2";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^=&\\s]+)=(.*?)(?=&[^=&\\s]+=|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
Map<String, String> res = new HashMap<String, String>();
while (m.find()) {
    res.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
}
System.out.println(res); // => {key1=valueforkey1==, key2=valueforkey2}
```